# If $|A| > \frac{|G|}{2} $ then $AA = G $

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

I'v found this proposition.

If $G$ is a finite  group , $ A \subset G $ a subset and $|A| > \frac{|G|}{2} $ then $AA = G $.

Why this is true ?

Comment: Found it where? Presumably, we're talking finite groups.

Comment: We had this before on math.stackexchange, but I don't know how to fed the search function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it is true.

let $A^{-1}=\{a^{-1}|a\in A\}$ then notice that $|A^{-1}|=|A|$ and let $x\in G$.

Now we can say that $|xA^{-1}|=|A|$ .Since $2|A|>|G|$ then $xA^{-1}$ and $A$ must intersect,otherwise we have contradiction.

Thus,we must have $xa_1^{-1}=a_2$ for some $a_1^{-1}\in A^{-1}$ and $a_2\in A\implies$ $x=a_1a_2\in AA$ we are done.

Comment: In your very last implication, you're using  the fact that $A$ is closed under miltiplication. Nevertheless $A$ is only a subset,  so...

Comment: $A$ is not closed under multiplication.

Comment: Oh it's $AA$! I'm sorry, $A$ prints as a blank character on my phone so the whole time I was considering $AA$ as $A$...

Comment: @GabrielR. :it is okey.