# Prove that any element of a group can be expressed as a product of elements in a subset.

Tags: group-theory

If X is a subset (not a subgroup)  of a finite group G, and X contains more than half of the elements in G. Show that for each element $g \in G \ ; g=ab \ ; a,b \in X$
My intuition is if you treat X like a coset, $xX$ it will generate G as you vary x. I'm not sure how to show that though. A hint given was that no theory is required.

Comment: more than have?

Comment: Oops, half. On mobile, I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: possible dupicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687715/if-a-fracg2-then-aa-g/687732#687732

Answer (score 0):

Let $X^{-1}$ be the set of inverses of elements of $X$.

For any $g\in G$, $(gX^{-1})\cap X$ is non-empty (Pigeonhole Principle). So $gb^{-1}=a$ for some $a$, $b\in X$. The result follows.