# Is it true that if $|A|>\frac{|G|}{2}$ then $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}=G$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, $A\subseteq G$ and put $A^{-1}=\{ a^{-1}:a\in A\}$.

Is it true that if $|A|>\frac{|G|}{2}$ then $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}=G$?

Comment: What operation are you representing by concatenation here?  Does $ AA^{-1} = \{ ab :  a \in A, b \in A^{-1} \} $

Comment: Obviously, yes.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687715/if-a-fracg2-then-aa-g), the proof is nearly identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any $g\in G$ then $|gA|=|A|>0.5|G|$ thus $(gA)\cap A\neq \emptyset .$ Let $c\in (gA)\cap A$ then $c=ga$ and therefore $g=ca^{-1}\in AA^{-1}.$