# An interesting property of $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $A$ be a non-empty subset of the symmetric group $S_3$ and put $A^{-1}=\{ a^{-1}:a\in A\}$.

Prove that:

(1) If  $|A|=3$ and $A$ is not a subgroup then $|A^{-1}A|=|AA^{-1}|=5$.

(2) If $|A|\neq 3$ then $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}\leq S_3$.

(Note that if $|A|\geq 4$ then $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}= S_3$, see 
[Is it true that if $|A|>\frac{|G|}{2}$ then $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}=G$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647169/is-it-true-that-if-a-fracg2-then-a-1a-aa-1-g)).

Comment: Solution. We have $S_3\cong \{ 1,a,a^2,b,c,d\}$ where $a^3=b^2=c^2=d^2=1$, $ab=c$ and $ba=d$. Let (without lose of generality)
$1\in A\subseteq S_3$. If $|A|=2$ then it s clear that $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}\leq S_3$, and if
$|A|=3$ then we have the following cases:\\
(a) $A=\{1,x,y\}$ where $x^2=y^2=1$, then $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}=\{1,x,y,xy,yx\}$,\\
(b) $A=\{ 1,a,x\}$ or $A=\{ 1,a^2,x\}$ where $x^2=1$ and $x\neq 1$, since $ax=xa^2$
then $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}=\{1,a,a^2,x, ax\}$, \\
(c) $A=\{ 1,a,a^2\}$, that is a subgroup of $S_3$. Finally, if $|A|\geq 4$ then $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}= S_3$.