# A property for infinite groups

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite group, $F$ a finite subset of $G$ and $A=G\setminus F$. Is it true that $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}=G$  (what about $AA=G$)?

($A^{-1}=\{ a^{-1}:a\in A\}$)

Comment: Yes (for all questions). This is essentially the same argumnet as in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687715/

Comment: Why?, note that the hypothesis of this question are completely different !(but with the same sentence)

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand True, but the argument is exactly the same: the cardinality of $A$ is strictly larger than that of $F$, so there must be an element in $A$ that is not disqualified by any element of $F$.  We're applying the same argument, not the same theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}=AA=G$.

Show just $A^{-1}A=G$, the others are similar.

Suppose there is a $g\in G$ with $g\notin A^{-1}A$. Then we have for every $a\in A$ that $g\notin a^{-1}A$ and so $ag\notin A$. So we have $Ag\cap A=\emptyset$ and so $Ag\subseteq G\setminus A$. This is contradiction to $|G\setminus A|<\infty$ since $A\to Ag, g\mapsto ag$ is bijective and so $|A|=|Ag|=\infty$.

Comment: This works even if G is finite, provided that |G|>2|F|.